where should I ask this recommendation questions? 
This site has spent some time discussing how to deal with recommendation questions. 
If this site is not the right place to ask, where is?  
If anything emerges, perhaps that info could be added to a FAQ as this site is a natural place for stackexchange users to wander into with "how do I start?" questions.
I have included my recommendation question below, but please don't answer it here, I don't want to incur the wrath of the half the site on my first day, by opening up a new exploit for gaming the sites conventions:
my question:
*how to find an online Mandarin tutor
I would like to try 1-on-1 lessons in conversational Mandarin with an instructor via Skype or simmilar.
From experience with other languages, I've found it easier to learn pronunciation from someone whose voice is about the same pitch as mine, so I am preferentially looking for a male teacher.
I've found a few sites like italki.com and chinadaily.com that have ads for teachers, few of the professional teachers on these sites are male.
Can you recommendation a male native speaker Mandarin online teacher, or a way to find such a teacher?
I am a beginning mandarin student.
I would like to learn Mandarin to fluency over the next few years.
*

Unfortunately, the question is not good for Meta either. I think you could try asking in our [Chat]. :) There it is ok. Sorry for the trouble, hope you stick around!

thank you, that was actually the perfect answer!
